# Object with auto execute procedures

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Is there a way to create an object with auto execute procedures? For example if a variable within this object has changed a private procedure kicks in and starts to do something?

Answer (score 7):

The language offers no such functionality. You have to implement it yourself.

Typically that's done by hiding the variable as a `private`, or better a `strict private`, and then ensure that all access to the variable is routed through a property. Then you can take whatever action you need in the property setter method.